# Core Data relationship one to one

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm creating a Core Data one-to-one relationship. My one-to-many relationship is working fine. My one-to-one not.
The problem is my public class.

For my one-to-many relationship I'm using an array. I don't know which one works for a simple string.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@objc(MeineSuchregionen)
public class MeineSuchregionen: NSManagedObject {
    var detailSuchregion: [DetailSuchregion]? {
        return self.rawDetailSuchregion?.array as? [DetailSuchregion]
    }

    convenience init?(title: String){
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

        guard let context = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext
            else {
                return nil
        }
        self.init(entity: MeineSuchregionen.entity(), insertInto: context)
        self.titlesuchregion = title
    }
}
```

So, when creating an object, it's always stored in array. That's a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A to-many relationship is represented by a set (and please name it in plural form)

```
@NSManaged public var detailSuchregionen: Set<DetailSuchregion>
```

A to-one relationship is represented by a standard property

```
@NSManaged public var detailSuchregion: DetailSuchregion?
```